# Posting a video using Tumblr API in java

Tags: java, android, api, tumblr

I am struggling with Tumblr api now.
When I post a text only, it is pretty simple because I just need to provide a string title and a string body.
Referring to the api doc ( http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#text-posts ), I used the following code and it worked successfully.

```
HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost(BASE_URL + "/blog/" + blog + ".tumblr.com/post");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "text"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", title));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", body));
hpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
consumer.sign(hpost);
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse resp = null;
resp = client.execute(hpost);
```

However, the problem is that when I post a video, I have to provide a string caption and an array player. ( http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#video-posts )
My question is, how can I pass an embed code to a NameValuePair object?
I just need to post a single video so the array will be of size 1.
I tried the following code:

```
HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost(BASE_URL + "/blog/" + blog + ".tumblr.com/post");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "video"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caption", title));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player", "<embed src='blah'>"));
```

but to no avail. 
If anyone can help with this, it will be really grateful. Thanks!

Comment: What status code do you get back from making the HTTP call? Are you sure Tumblr isn't validating your embed code, and rejecting the call if invalid?

Comment: Looking at the Tumblr API document that you linked to, it looks like the RESPONSE contains the caption and a player array.  Two more things, the linked api is for Video post retrieval, not posting a video.  And secondly this api is accessed via HttpGet...not HttpPost.

Comment: When I use the first code to post a text, it works. When I use the second code to post a video, I get the following one. {"response":{"posts":[]},"meta":{"status":200,"msg":"OK"}}

Comment: The section: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting contains the parameters you want to use: caption,embed,data   For this call it would be an HttpPost....

Comment: Opps... my bad... I was so stupid lol.. Thanks Brian!

Answer (score 2):

The values caption and and array player on are on the Response from querying a video plog post. Not the parameters for adding a new vide post. The section: tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting contains the parameters you want to use: caption,embed,data  (all strings...)